# \csname problem

Tags: pgffor, csname

I try to pass a list of nodes and angles to a command, and I need to name them for a futur use, but I make a mystake that I don't understand.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\makeatletter

\newcommand{\TRAA}[1]{%
    % node/angle list
    \foreach \x/\y [count=\i from 1] in {#1} {%
        \expandafter\xdef\csname Pt@\i\endcsname\x
        \expandafter\xdef\csname Ang@\i\endcsname\y
    }
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

essai

\TRAA{A/71,B/45}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\expandafter\xdef\csname Pt@\i\endcsname{\x}\expandafter\xdef\csname Ang@\i\endcsname{\y}`

Comment: `\def` (and `\xdef`) require braces around the replacement text. although better might be to use `\let` (and no brace) rather than `\xdef`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It doesn't work in a foreach loop.

Comment: you need `\global\expandafter\let\csname...` for same reason you used xdef not def

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ok. Except the syntax diffrence and the braces, is there an hiden reson to prefer the one or the other approach ?

Comment: @Tarass `\let` is (marginally) more efficient and in general it's safer although here I think you know in advance that the content of `\x` is safe in an edef as it is necessarily  the characters in your initial list (but if that contained, say accented characters or any tex commands, they would fail in an xdef)